# Can't resolve all parameters for Modal: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Modal } from 'ionic-angular';

import { PopupPage } from '../../components/modal/modal.page';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/spot/spot.html',
  providers: [ Modal ]
})
export class SpotComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(Modal) private modal: Modal ) {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put modalcomponent code here. Problem is in modalcomponent's constructor.

Comment: It's an ionic ocmponent. It is not my code.

Comment: Okay then. Error says it cant find dependencies reuired for modal when modal is initiated.

Comment: But wait I m not an ionic guy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Modal isn't meant to be injected.  Looking at the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/Modal/) it appears a Modal is always meant to be constructed with `Modal.create`.  I believe Angular is trying to do its best and construct one for you but since Modal doesn't have a no-arg constructor and isn't marked `@Injectable` there is little it can do.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also, on that same line, Modal is not meant to be a provider and shouldn't be in your providers array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @Pace commented, you can take a look at [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/Modal/) to see how to *create* a `Modal`.

You don't have to include it in the `providers` array or in your `constructor` like you're doing. Instead you should use the `Modal.create(...)` method like this:

```
import { Modal, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class HomePage {

 constructor(/* ..., */ private nav: NavController) {
   // Your code...
 }

 presentProfileModal() {
   // Create the modal using the layout from the Profile Component
   let profileModal = Modal.create(Profile, { paramId: 12345 });

   // Show the modal
   this.nav.present(profileModal);
 }

}

@Component(...)
class Profile {

 constructor(/* ..., */ private params: NavParams) {
   // Get the parameter by using NavParams
   console.log('paramId', params.get('paramId'));
 }

}
```